# cors on uploaded site only

Tags: reactjs, api

I made an API call to `https://testnets-api.opensea.io/assets?asset_contract_address=0x608BE279cD4E841b7b2bd75319054De51b04E673&order_direction=asc` to get my data of nfts.it worked but when I uploaded it shows this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://testnets-api.opensea.io/assets?asset_contract_address=0x608BE279cD4E841b7b2bd75319054De51b04E673&order_direction=asc'
> from origin 'https://mthree.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

CORS blocked your POST request.
You need to whitelist your domain (https://mthree.netlify.app) at the server end.

Take a look at what actually CORS is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS